# Is it "supported" to call method on nil reference in Delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi

The following Delphi program calls method upon nil reference and runs fine.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TX = class
    function Str: string;
  end;

function TX.Str: string;
begin
  if Self = nil then begin
    Result := 'nil'
  end else begin
    Result := 'not nil'
  end;
end;

begin
  Writeln(TX(nil).Str);
  Readln;
end.
```

However, in a structurally similar C# program, `System.NullReferenceException` will be raised, which seems to be the right thing to do.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TX
    {
        public string Str()
        {
            if (this == null) { return "null"; }
            return "not null";    
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(((TX)null).Str());
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Because TObject.Free uses such style, it seems to be "supported" to call method on nil reference in Delphi. Is this true ? (Let's suppose that in the `if Self = nil` branch, no instance field will be accessed.)

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040860/why-would-you-check-for-assignedself-in-object-methods

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you very much for the valuable information !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is reasonable to call a method on a `nil` reference, subject to the following rules:

1. The method must not be virtual or dynamic. That is because virtual or dynamic methods are bound using the runtime type of the reference. And if the reference is `nil` then there is no runtime type. By way of contrast, non-virtual, non-dynamic methods are bound at *compile* time.
2. You are allowed to read the value of `Self`, for instance to compare it against `nil`.
3. In case `Self` is `nil`, then you must not refer to any instance variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Could you comment whether you get these rules from official documentations, especially the part about `not virtual (or dynamic)` ? I did not find any official documentation page (or DelphiBasics page) saying so.

Comment: @XichenLi, the VMT table is initialized in the constructor. Without initialization, a virtual (dynamic) call does not work.

Comment: @XichenLi, see [Internal Data Formats.Class Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Class_Types).

Comment: I'm not sure about documentation of this, but what I stated above is just what I know to be true.

Comment: @LURD Thank you for your help very much ! I am still confused. Why calling regular method works ? It needs to check `vmtMethodTable` in the VMT table anyway. If VMT table is not initialized, how can it find the entry point ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Does your statement `it does not work because there is no runtime type when the reference is nil` mean the same thing as LU RD's statement `it does not work because VMT table is not initialized when the reference is nil` ?.... O_O

Comment: We are stating the same thing in different ways. I've expressed it in a higher level way, by pointing out that virtual and dynamic binding requires knowledge of the runtime type. That happens to be implemented by a VMT or DMT, but those are implementation details. On the other hand non virtual, non dynamic methods are bound at compile time.

Comment: @XichenLi *Why calling regular method works ? It needs to check vmtMethodTable in the VMT table anyway.* No, that is not so. These methods are bound at compile time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you very much for your helpful comments !

Comment: @David - I think it worth saying that violation of any of these rules will not be caught by the compiler and doing so will result in a generic "access violation" exception rather than a more helpfully diagnostic error identifying the specific transgression of these rules (e.g. NulLReferenceException).  An experienced developer should be able to deduce a NIL reference from the details of the access violation error message, but it is not spelled out in the same way that the specific exception in .NET does for you.